# How do i display list of applications already installed on android phone in listview?

Tags: android, android-layout

Ok i am using this code to get the list of applications on the phone but how do i display them on screen?

```
final PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();

    List<applicationinfo> packages = pm
            .getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);

    for (ApplicationInfo packageInfo : packages) {

        Log.d(TAG, "Installed package :" + packageInfo.packageName);
        Log.d(TAG,
                "Launch Activity :"
                        + pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageInfo.packageName));

    }
```

Im trying to display them in a listview but im having a bit of trouble. Could someone please help?

Comment: See [this post](http://androidboss.com/getting-list-of-installed-applications-in-android/).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This might be of some help to you.

```
public class AppList extends Activity {
 private ListView lView;
 private ArrayList results = new ArrayList();

 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.main);
  lView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list1);
  PackageManager pm = this.getPackageManager();

  Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
  intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);

  List<ResolveInfo> list = pm.queryIntentActivities(intent, PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
  for (ResolveInfo rInfo : list) {
   results.add(rInfo.activityInfo.applicationInfo.loadLabel(pm).toString());
   Log.w("Installed Applications", rInfo.activityInfo.applicationInfo.loadLabel(pm).toString());
  } 
  lView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, results));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create an Adapter which implements ListAdapter. As basis you can use the BaseAdapter. For more info you could visit [this tutorial](http://blog.app-solut.com/2011/03/using-custom-layouts-for-spinner-or-listview-entries-in-android/)